# Python's ==, in the land of Haskell

Tags: haskell

A sample code that shows how two objects can be compared in Python using `==` operator:

```python
class Person:
  def __init__(name):
    this.name = name

  def __eq__(nextPerson):
    if this.name == nextPerson.name:
      return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
   personOne = Person("saran")
   personTwo = Person("madhavan")
   personThree = Person("saran")
   print personOne == personTwo
   print personOne == personThree
```

This must print:

```python
False
True
```

How can I write the above code using `Eq` typeclass in Haskell?

Comment: So... what have you tried? What do you know about Haskell's `Eq` and what is your equivalent of `Person` in haskell? I can guess, but that kind of thing should be part of the question.

Comment: I think that your Python have some issues....

Comment: Python doesn't have the `new` keyword; also `if <bool>: return True; else: return False` is reduced to just `return <bool>`.

Comment: hi Erik, i removed the new keyword... about the if else error, the `return False` is left indented by one level actually which is like an else here....

Comment: He meant that `a==b: return true; else: return false` is the same as just `return a==b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Person = Person { name::String } deriving (Show)

instance Eq Person where
    x == y = (name x) == (name y)

main = do
    let personOne = Person { name="saran" }
    let personTwo = Person { name="madhavan" }
    let personThree = Person { name="saran" }
    print $ personOne == personTwo
    print $ personOne == personThree
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that this Eq instance is equivalent to the automatically derived one.

Comment: @Cubic: In this case, yes. In a more general case where there are fields other than `name`, no. (Not saying you are wrong, just explaining why I decided to actually implement `Eq`.)